# laravel handler always return false when i use spatie middleware

Tags: laravel, api, middleware, laravel-passport, laravel-permission

I'm trying to create permissions and roles for users in a Laravel API Project. I'm using Passport and Spatie's Permission package. Using that I added a middleware:

Route

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    /** Roles Route */
        Route::get('roles',[RoleController::class, 'index'])->middleware('permission:role-list');
}
```

Handler.php:

```php
        public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
            return response()->json(['User does not have the right roles.'],403);
        }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Controller:

```php
        function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('permission:role-list', ['only' => ['index']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-create', ['only' => ['store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-edit', ['only' => ['update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:role-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        return response(['role' => $roles], 200);

    }
```

I created an admin account and it was given all the existing permissions, but whenever I ask for the route, it shows me that error message:

> User does not have the right roles.

I checked the database and the user had all the required permissions for that.

Comment: Have you cleared your role/ permission cache?

Comment: @SuperDJ Yes and the problem still. maybe the problem is how I use the middleware??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add the package middlewares in the `Kernel.php` as described [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/middleware#package-middleware).

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ... other middleware
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
];
```

Depending on where you want to define the permissions to access a method either define them in the Controller or on the route. Adding them to both the route and Controller is only doing the same thing.

Changing something in the `Handler.php` should not be required.

Note that permissions can have different [guards](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/multiple-guards). For example it can be `web` or `api`.

After changing roles or permissions it sometimes helps to reset the cache. Resetting the cache can be done with `php artisan permission:cache-reset` [command](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/artisan).

Comment: Thank you it worked after the command tell me.